# Using htaccess to remove .php and allow path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I currently have a .htaccess file that allows people to enter the URL without the php extension, such that http://domain.com/account redirects to account.php

I would like to be able to have it so that if I enter http://domain.com/account/contactinfo (or http://domain.com/account/settings/groups and so on) it still goes to account.php, but I am not sure how to change what I have to achieve this.

Current .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+)?$ $1.php
```

Any help appreciated! Obviously if there exists a folder it should follow that path (e.g. if /folder/page.php exists, then http://domain.com/folder/page/create would go to folder/page.php)

Comment: In cases where users go to `/account/contactinfo` or similar, do you need to pass any information about the additional URI parts as a query string or anything?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes I would like query strings passed as normal

Comment: What I meant was, do you need to take pieces of the URI and pass it as a query string like `/account/contactinfo` would redirect to `/account.php?q=contactinfo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this is you don't need to pass any URI info into query string (i.e. your app will still look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+)(/[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]*)?$ $1.php&q=$2 [QSA]
# Note the optional '&q=$2' on line above if you want to make removed part of URI available as passed parameter

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

Note that since I removed the condition to check for a valid php file, I added a second conditional rewrite rule to just redirect to site root if the re-written request does not point to a valid PHP file. You could obviously redirect this to a 404 page or whatever else you might want to redirect to. Or you could remove this altogether and let Apache give it's default 404 response.

Comment: Hmm.. odd.  The `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` should be written in the first rule to `/*.php` which is a real file name and that should be the basis of the second condition.  First can you verify that the first rewrite is working as expected?  The second part is more nice to have I would think.  It may also help to add the flags R & L to the first rule for troubleshooting purposes like `[R,L,QSA]`.  This will temporarily lose the clean URL's but will allow you to see in your browser how the rewrite is actually behaving.

Comment: I figured it out. the first rewrite rule should rewrite to $1.php not to /$1.php - now it works! Thanks

Comment: Oh... so so are working within a subdirectory or something?  Sorry about that. I actually changed that from your preliminary value, as I typically work with .htaccess in web root and like to explicitly state the rewritten URI relative to root. I guess actually that would mess up the second Rewrite rule which would need to be `^/.*$` :P  I fixed in my answer.

Comment: Although further testing shows that the php _SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable gets lost in this process (and I need it! :) )

Comment: @BenHolness You can't get at that via `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` ?

Comment: @BenHolness I have also added an optional line in my answer in case you need to get the removed URI components in query_string. Obviously you should still be able to get these in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` since there is not a browser redirect involved.

Comment: Almost there! One more issue is that multiple paths caused problems. I fixed this by changing the rewrite rule to (note I also put the first / outside of $2) : RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-_\.\/]*)?$ $1.php?path_info=$2 [QSA]